# rubymine column selection mode select few lines

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I'm trying to edit in column selection mode on Rubymine but I have some lines I wish to skip.
In the code below I would like to edit both "to_change" at the same time.
I wish to duplicate the cursor and every edit action will occur in them both.
In this code if I will select the start of both "to_change" and press '#', the code here:

```
def a
  to_change
end

def b
  to_change
end
```

will turn to

```
def a
  #to_change
end

def b
  #to_change
end
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. Which lines do you want to skip?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. The only text I want to change is 'to_change' skipping the 'end', empty line, and 'def', so writing again will override only to_change code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple selection/editing is not supported yet, you can [follow this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80056).